# Video upload using the vimeo api in node js is not working properly?

Tags: javascript, vimeo-api

I am trying to upload video to vimeo.The Ajax post is aborted.but the video is saved in vimeo.but unable to play.it says error wile uploading.

Belo is my code

```
function testVideoUpload1(callback){
var Vimeo = require('vimeo').Vimeo;
//CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN
var vimeoDetails = reactConfig.vimeoDetails;
var lib = new Vimeo(vimeoDetails.clientId, vimeoDetails.clientSecret, vimeoDetails.clientAccessToken);

lib.streamingUpload("/AppGenFlux/Wildlife.wmv", function (err, body, status, headers) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log("eror = "+err);
    }
    console.log("status = "+status);
    console.log("location = "+headers.location);
    // callback(body);
     lib.request(headers.location, function (error, body, status_code, headers) {
         console.log(1);
         console.log(body);
     });
});
```

}

Comment: If we not specify the path also same out coming.i think this is path problem

Comment: I noticed you created and closed a ticket in the library (https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.js/issues/31). Have you resolved this issue?